# Can users be subscribed to a list rather than a card

Tags: trello, notifications

New to Trello. I'm using two different outsourced/overseas workers to edit/post web pages that I initiate. So I set up a board that has lists like "keyword research," "transcribe draft," "code page," "upload," "QA," etc.

My concept is that I initiate a new page and make a card for it. Then when I move that card to a new list, the appropriate worker gets an e-mail so they know they have a new task to do.

When they are done, they move that card to the next list, at which time another worker is notified that it is their turn to work on it.

But I don't see any way to assign these workers to lists like this. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Since the end of August, you're able to subscribe to lists and also boards:
[Trello Blog: Board and List Subscribe, Desktop Notification Updates, Edit Comments, and More!](http://blog.trello.com/board-and-list-subscribe-desktop-notifications-edit-comments-and-more/)

[image]

Comment: To be clear, though, this is something each user would have to do. You cannot assign other people to a list.

Comment: @IanHenry, you're right. Thanks for clarifying.